# Add products to order after payment (WooCommerce/Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am creating a 'Build Your Own' page. After selecting 4 products from the options, 1 main product gets added to the basket with 4 of the selected products being added as meta_data under that main product.

You can see below the main product with 4 selected products (IDs).

[image]

After paying for this item, I need to add each selected product to the order, so that they are within the order on the backend. I'm having to do it like this, because I need the stock of the selected product to go down, eventually pulling into a stock management system we use (veeqo)

Any help is appreciated. The code below allows me get the some meta_data for woocommerce_thankyou but I am not sure if it will work then...

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'BuildYourOwn', 10, 1);
function BuildYourOwn( $order_id ) {
    if ( !$order_id ){
        return;
    }
    $firstTime = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_thankyou_action_done', true );
    // Allow code execution only once 
    if( !$firstTime ) {

        // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        $exItems = '';
        // Loop through order items
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
            //print_r($item);
            // Get the product object
            $product = $item->get_product();

            // Get the product sku
            $product_sku = $product->get_sku();

            // Get the product name
            $product_id = $product->get_name();

            $extras = $item->get_formatted_meta_data('_', true);
            
            $exItems.=$product_sku;

            if(!empty($extras)){
                $exItems.=$product_sku.' -';
                
                foreach($extras as $extra){
                    $exItems.= ' ['.$extra->key.' : '. preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9?@,.&%!\s]/","",$extra->value).'] ';
                }
                
            }
            $exItems.="\n";

        }
        
        var_dump($exItems);
```

Comment: What **exactly** is your problem/question? What have you tried, where are you stuck at?

Comment: I need to add these 4 selected products into the order after the customer pays so they show on the backend.

Comment: If it is purely about the stock (correct me if I am wrong), why not apply stock reduction to those certain products after the order is payed 
versus add those products to the order?

Comment: It cannot get reduced from stock because our stock management system won't pick it up. These 4 meta_data item IDs need to get added to the order and the customer paid

Comment: Via `$order->add_product( $product, $qty, $args );` you can add products to an existing order. Since your question is not about default (build your own: how is this done? via a plugin? which one?) functionality in WooCommerce I cannot test/try this in my own setup. So I prefer not to answer questions like this because then it becomes trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I worded the question wrong - But I figured it out:

I used the code below to get the meta_data which I then looped through and got individual item id and added it to the basket this way.

```
// Get the product meta data
        $extras = $item->get_formatted_meta_data('_', true);
        
        
        if ($product_id == 60023){

            if(!empty($extras)){
                
                $args = array(
                    'subtotal'     => 0,
                    'total'        => 0,
                  );
                
                foreach($extras as $extra){
                    $mini_name = $extra->value;
                    
                    $mini = get_page_by_title( $mini_name, OBJECT, 'product' );
                    $mini_id = $mini->ID; 
                    
                    $order->add_product( wc_get_product($mini_id), 1, $args); // Add Minis
                }
            }
        }
```

The only slight issue is woocommerce_thankyou hook not firing if paypal users don't come back to the site after paying.